# DRY approach to accessing instance value in custom Django ImageField form field?

Tags: python, django

I'm using [django-storages](http://code.welldev.org/django-storages/wiki/S3Storage) to save images uploaded to S3, and I want to create a custom form field that will display the image when editing, along with an option to change it.

The problem I'm running into is the path's value that is stored in my database is not the full path to the image, as django-storages does the generating of the full path.

Settings.py:

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'myBucketName'
AWS_LOCATION = 'mySubBucketName'
```

models.py:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_image = ImageField(upload_to='upload/path')
```

Example of accessing full url:

```
>>> mymod = MyModel.objects.get(id=1)
>>> print mymod.my_image
upload/path/somefile.jpg
>>> print mymod.my_image.url
https://s3.amazonaws.com/myBucketName/mySubBucketName/upload/path/somefile.jpg
```

I am not seeing how I can access mymod.my_image.url() from within a custom Widget (where I would be render()'ing something like this:

```
class ImageViewWidget(forms.Widget):
    markup = """
        <img src="%(imagepath)"/>
        <input type="file" name="%(name)s"/>
        """

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        output = self.markup % {
            "name": name,
            "imagepath": "<<<< MAGIC CODE GOES HERE >>>>"
        }
        return mark_safe(output)
```

**Update:**
I'm looking for a DRY approach to this problem.  My apologies for not clarifying this from the beginning

Comment: I'm still looking for a DRY approach to this problem.  Does django-storages and/or Django not a small change to support what I want to do?

Answer (score 2):

I think overriding the `__init__` in your custom widget and passing in your url would do the trick.

**edit:**

```
class ImageViewWidget(forms.Widget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.path = kwargs.pop('path', '')
        super(ImageViewWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    markup = """
        <img src="%(imagepath)"/>
        <input type="file" name="%(name)s"/>
        """

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        output = self.markup % {
            "name": name,
            "imagepath": self.path
        }
        return mark_safe(output)

class MyModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        image_url = ''
        if self.instance:
            image_url = self.instance.my_image.url
        super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['my_image'].widget=ImageViewWidget(path=image_url)
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is it requires all forms using the widget to pass this information in.  I was hoping Django had some magic hook to do this, but apparently not

Comment: Sorry when i first read your comment i thought you meant all form classes would need to have to have overriden widgets. I didn't know you were concerned only at the instance level. The edit should give you what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a [ModelForm](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#a-full-example) to generate the form that is rendered using the widget you can have that pass the value to the widget, requires the code to be written once.

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, Textarea

class AuthorForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ('name', 'title', 'birth_date')
        widgets = {
            'name': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 20}),
        }
```

So in your case it might be:

```
class MyModelForm(ModelForm):
     class Meta:
          model = MyModel
     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          image_url = ''
    if self.instance:
        image_url = self.instance.my_image.url
        super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['my_image'].widget=ImageViewWidget(path=image_url)
```

self.instance should provide access to the model as long as it has been set when creating the ModelForm.

Comment: sorry for lagging on reply; I tried your above code, but get message, 'self' not defined.  If something like this can work, this is exactly what I need

Comment: @dolan That'll teach me to not test my answers... Kriegar got there first with his edit to use init to access instance